# If $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ are complex number in argand plane satisfying $z_1+z_3=z_2+z_4.\;$ Then $(i)$area of triangle formed by $z, z_1, z_2$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

If $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ are complex number in argand plane satisfying $z_1+z_3=z_2+z_4.\;$ A complex number $'z'$ lies on line Joining $z_1$ and $z_4$ such that $Arg\bigg(\dfrac{z-z_2}{z_1-z_2}\bigg)=Arg\bigg(\dfrac{z_3-z_2}{z-z_2}\bigg).\;$ It is given that $|z-z_4|=5,\;|z-z_2|=|z-z_3|=6.\;$ Then  Find

$(i)$area of triangle formed by $z, z_1, z_2$

$(ii)$ area of the quadrilateral formed by the points $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ taken is order.

**My Thinking:**

I took quadrilateral $A(z_1), B(z_2), C(z_3), D(z_4)$.

It is given that $z_1+z_3=z_2+z_4\; \implies$ mid point of $AC$ and $BD$ will be same.

Also from properties of argument $Arg\bigg(\dfrac{z-z_2}{z_1-z_2}\bigg)=Arg\bigg(\dfrac{z_3-z_2}{z-z_2}\bigg)\;\implies\; Arg(z-z_2)-Arg(z_1-z_2)=Arg(z_3-z_2)-Arg(z-z_2)+2k\pi, (where \;k\in \{-1,0,1\})$

$\implies\;2Arg(z-z_2)=Arg(z_3-z_2)+Arg(z_1-z_2)+2k\pi$.

Now i am stuck. I cannot proceed further.

**Can anyone provide me its solution or some more hint?**

Comment: Did you figure out that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram and the line segment from $B$ to $z$ bisects $\angle ABC$?

Comment: @TedShifrin yes i figured that out from $z_1+z_3=z_2+z_4$

Comment: @TedShifrin I got the answer.